# Using CTS/RTS hardware flow control on USB

Tags: linux, serial-port

I am trying to run a Roland MDX-20 milling machine using a Raspberry Pi. The machine has a small input buffer and uses hardware flow control to signal when it has completed a command and can receive a new one. I have tried to set the correct serial settings using

```
stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 9600 cs8 -parenb -cstopb -clocal crtscts
```

but when I send it using the cat command;

```
cat ~/(my RML file) > /dev/ttyUSB0
```

All of the data gets sent out at once.

I have a Startech.com USB Serial cable that other windows users have reported as working, so I don't think the cable is at fault, but more the serial drivers possibly?

Any ideas on how to get around this?

Thanks

Comment: You should also make the terminal *raw* (turn off line buffering, special characters, etc: `stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 raw crstcts ...`). What chipset is that "startech.com" cable using (you can gather the info from lsusb).

Answer (score 1):

The startech site currently lists multiple USB <-> serial cable products. And those different products use different chipsets, i.e. at least FTDI and Prolific ones. And only the Prolific ones seem to support hardware flow control.

You can check whether you have a Prolific or FTDI USB device by looking at the `dmesg` while connecting the device.

When you have verified your USB cable you can debug hardware flow control by running [`statserial`](http://manpath.be/f34/1/statserial) in a separate terminal.

---

In case your serial device isn't directly connected to the USB <-> serial cable it makes sense to check the connections of that additional cable, as well.

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary workaround until you find the problem, you can use `pv` to restrict the throughput, eg to 100bytes/sec:

```
pv -L 100 -q < ~/my_RML_file > /dev/ttyUSB0
```